# C# запись в string переменную одного слеша

Tags: c#, файловая-система, пути, readline

Я ввожу в `Console.ReadLine()` текст, например `C:\test\1.txt\`, а вижу через отладчик что в переменной сейчас `C:\\test\\1.txt\\`,(c двумя бекслешами) можно ли это исправить, то есть сделать чтобы было только по одному?

Comment: зачем вам это нужно? Вы если будете эту строку куда то выводить, в консоль или файл, там будет 1 слеш.

Comment: интересно, вообще, возможно ли это. Может через Replace()?

Comment: что возможно то? Чтобы заставить платформу .NET по другому внетренне представлять строку? Одинарный слеш - это управляющий символ для строки. Например, при помощи вот такой конструкции `\t` можно представить табуляцию, при помощи `\n` - символ перевода на новую строку. Потому строка должна ка то понять, что вы не управляющий символ хотите, а просто слеш - вот она его для себя представляет как жва слеша `\\`

Comment: А что насчёт использования памяти, будет ли использоваться больше если двойной бекслеш в строке?

Comment: тож самое будет по памяти. Ну вот попробуйте один символ создать и поглядеть в дебаге на него `'\n'` или `'\\'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вас сбил с толку отладчик. Это не в памяти 2 слэша, а отладчик вам показывает два вместо одного. Это сделно чтобы не путать одинарный слэш с escape-символами `\r\n\t\b\0` и т.д.

Это просто такое отображение отладчиком, для удобства. Так что то, о чем вы пишете в вопросе - на самом деле не так. Строка записана в память ровно так как вы ее записали, никаких двойных слэшей там на самом деле нет.

Но давайте убедимся в этом на практике. Как известно, символы в строке, да и вообще все символы в C# - это юникод кодировка UTF-16, а это значит, что каждый символ будет занимать ровно 2 байта *(если быть точнее, то не менее 2 байт, но в рамках нашего примера это не существенно, и болше актуально для китайских иероглифов)*.

Давайте распечатаем все символы вместе с их фактическими адресами в памяти. Для прямого доступа к памяти я буду использовать небезопасный `unsafe` код.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = "Hello\\World"; // литерал строки можно записать точно так же как вы видите ее в отладчике
    string text2 = @"Hello\World"; // а это "буквальное" представление строки, удобно его использовать, когда вам надо написать например путь к файлу 

    Console.WriteLine(text == text2); // если выведет True, значит строки одинаковые
    PrintStringMemoryLayout(text);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static unsafe void PrintStringMemoryLayout(string text)
{
    int ptrSize = sizeof(void*); // 4 для x86, 8 для x64
    string header = "Адрес".PadRight(ptrSize * 2 + 1) + "Символ";
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', header.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(header);
    fixed (char* ptr = text)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            long addr = (long)(ptr + i);
            char c = *(ptr + i);
            Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString("x2").PadLeft(ptrSize * 2, '0') + " " + c);
        }
    }
}
```

Получаем следующий вывод в консоль.

```
True
-----------------------
Адрес            Символ
000002070ee7b72c H
000002070ee7b72e e
000002070ee7b730 l
000002070ee7b732 l
000002070ee7b734 o
000002070ee7b736 \
000002070ee7b738 W
000002070ee7b73a o
000002070ee7b73c r
000002070ee7b73e l
000002070ee7b740 d
```

Как видно, в памяти всего один слеш и он занимает ровно 2 байта. Что вполне на практике доказывает, что это отладчик имеет такое особое отображение строк, а не то что с хранением строк что-то не то (позднее вы вы даже будете считать это полезной возможностью отладчика).

Читать далее:

- [Руководство по программированию C#: Строки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/)
- [Буквальный идентификатор - @](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)
- [Интерполяция строк - $](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: Суррогатные пары занимают 4 байта. Это один символ.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пока я не забрёл в диапазон CJK, это не существенно. :) Добавил уточнение.